# How do you set the font in BlueJ?

Tags: bluej

I am currently using BlueJ for programming. Is there a preferences/options menu to change the font to something like Courier?

this is kinda trivial, but I couldn't find anything on google.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've tried this on version 3.1.6, I think it'll work on all BlueJ versions.

You can navigate to C:\Program Files (x86)\BlueJ\lib and there in the bluej.defs file you can change the font:

```
/* these two parameters have to be set like this on line 329 an 330 */
#bluej.lookAndFeel=system
#bluej.lookAndFeel=crossplatform

/* the same for parameter in line 351 */
bluej.useTheme=true
```

For the terminal you set the font with

```
bluej.terminal.font=Monospaced
```

For the menu:

```
bluej.menu.font=SansSerif-bold
```

and so on... there are more font parameters for other parts of the program and there are also ones for changing the font size or color (line 458)

There is also another file for changing some BlueJ parameters. In moe.defs in the same folder. There you can change the colors of different parts of the program with hexadecimal values. You can also configure the buttons of the toolbars of BlueJ. It is very well explained in the file itself.

[The image shows an example for changed BlueJ settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AhhyI.png)

Comment: I must add, that the change in font takes effect only after I reboot my PC. I am using Linux.

Answer (score 1):

You should see the toolbar on top of the main BlueJ window (Windows) or the top of the laptop screen (Mac). Then you go *Tools* -> *Preferences* -> *Change font size*. Unfortunately you can't change the font style.

Answer (score 1):

Worth a try. Since I am using Linux, I headed over to the BlueJ folder in /usr/share/BlueJ.

Over there, I found a JAR called blueJeditor.jar
Try to extract its files. Next locate the BlueJ->Editor->Editor.class

Now try using jd-gui to decompile this class. Here, you might be able to change some attributes which can help change fonts.
A tedious task indeed :)

Answer (score 1):

Its very simple...just follow these steps:

1. Download version 3.1.1 from here: https://www.bluej.org/versions.html
2. Navigate to the location where you have installed java version **3.1.1**, then go to lib folder and then open bluej.defs.
3. Just copy everything which is there
4. Download the version on which you want 'Courier New' font, from: https://www.bluej.org/versions.html
5. Navigate to the location where you have installed **new** java version, then go to lib folder and then open bluej.defs.
6. Select all: 'Ctrl + a' in Windows and 'Command + a' in Mac, then press 'Ctrl + v' in Windows and 'Command + v', just to paste the data from Java version 3.1.1's java.defs file to that of the new version.
7. Save the Java new version's java.defs file
8. Open the new version...Tada!! It works!

I have tried in version 5.0.1 version (the newest till now), and it worked successfully

Upvote if it worked